# Converting unicode data back to dicts/strings

Tags: python, django, dictionary, unicode

I am attempting to use a function in Python and it seems I am getting a type error. I am using Django, and am getting the values of one variable through a get request, and two others from a Model query. For some reason, all three are of type unicode, while I need them to be strings/dict for this function. The function code (some is omitted for convenience):

```
content = request.POST.get('status', False)
auth = Authority.objects.get(app_name=appname)
encrypted = encrypt(auth.p_key, content, auth.policy)

print type(auth.p_key), type(content), type(auth.policy)
print auth.p_key, content, auth.policy
```

Now when I stored `p_key` and `policy`, they were a dict and a string, respectively. But when I print the types, it gives me `<type 'unicode'> <type 'unicode'> <type 'unicode'>`. Then, when the `encrypt` function is run, the outcome is incorrect and the error message appears:

> type mismatch between `src='<type 'unicode'>' and targ='<type 'dict'>'`

Then when I print the actual values, they come out as

```
{'h': <pairing.Element object at 0x103273d20>, 'e_gg_alpha': <pairing.Element 
object at0x1032a3810>, 'g2': <pairing.Element object at 0x103273a08>, 'g': 
<pairing.Element object at 0x103273b28>, 'f': <pairing.Element object at 
0x1032a3078>} adfadfadsf (a or b)
```

Which appears to be a dict and two strings, exactly what I am looking for. I tried using `ast.literal_eval` to convert the unicode to a dict, as has been suggested in many places, but I simply get a SyntaxError in the ast.py file.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Authority model and encrypt function code:

```
class Authority(models.Model):
    app_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    attr_list = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    p_key = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    d_key = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    policy = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.app_name

def encrypt(self, pk, M, object):
        key = self.group.random(GT)
        c1 = abenc.encrypt(pk, key, object)
        cipher = AuthenticatedCryptoAbstraction(sha1(key))
        c2 = cipher.encrypt(M)
        return { 'c1':c1, 'c2':c2 }
```

Comment: Could you show the `Authority` model definition?

Comment: Try printing `repr(auth.p_key)` etc. It's possible that they are string (unicode) representations of your dicts

Comment: And you're going to need to show the code for `encrypt()`.

Comment: Added Authority and encrypt() code